# Azure CLI - acb.yaml does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-acr

I am trying to create a scheduled ACR task to delete old images from storage using this command:

```
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'worker:.*' --untagged --ago 1d"
 az acr task create --name remove_old_images_worker --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" --schedule
 "0 0 * * *" --registry registry --context /dev/null
```

But it returns me an error with this:

```
acb.yaml does not exist.
```

And what is also interesting is that it worked for a similar task just a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I solved this problem using Terraform as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry_task" "acr_purge_task" {
  name                  = "scheduledAcrPurgeTask"
  container_registry_id = azurerm_container_registry.registry.id
  platform {
    os           = "Linux"
    architecture = "amd64"
  }
  encoded_step {
    task_content = <<EOF
    version: v1.1.0
    steps:
    - cmd: acr purge --filter '.*:^((?!prod|dev).)*$' --untagged --ago 7d
    disableWorkingDirectoryOverride: true
    timeout: 3600
    EOF
  }
  agent_setting {
    cpu = 2
  }
  timer_trigger {
    name     = "t1"
    schedule = "0 0 * * Tue"
    enabled  = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "acb.yaml does not exist" implies that the Azure CLI is expecting to find an `acb.yaml` file in the context location you've specified. If you're specifying `/dev/null` as the context, it's unclear why the CLI would expect to find a file there unless there's a bug or a temporary issue with the CLI or the ACR service. When creating scheduled tasks in Azure Container Registry (ACR) using the Azure CLI, the `--context` parameter is used to specify the location of the source code, which typically contains a `acb.yaml`

However, for a purge task that only runs a command without needing a build context, you should use the special value `--context /dev/null`.

Instead of using `/dev/null`, try using a dummy context with an empty `acb.yaml` file:

```
mkdir dummy-context
```

[image]

```
touch dummy-context/acb.yaml
```

[image]

```
az acr task create \
  --name remove_old_images_worker \
  --registry <registryname>\
  --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" \
  --schedule "0 0 * * *" \
  --context /dev/null \
  --commit-trigger-enabled false \
  --pull-request-trigger-enabled false
```

[image]

Needless to say below things must be ensured first.

- the necessary permissions to create tasks in the ACR.
- latest version of the Azure CLI installed
- there are no typos or missing arguments in the command
- have you reached a limit on the number of tasks you
  can create in your ACR.

Additionally, make sure that you are running the command in the correct directory where the `acb.yaml` file is located. If you are running the command from a different directory, you may need to specify the full path to the `acb.yaml` file using the `--context` parameter.

References:

- [Automatically purge images from an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge#automatically-purge-images-from-an-azure-container-registry)
- [Tutorial: Run an ACR task on a defined schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-scheduled#tutorial-run-an-acr-task-on-a-defined-schedule)
- [Similar issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1425774/im-trying-to-creating-az-acr-task-with-purge-comma)

Comment: Creating empty acb.yaml allowed to create task, but it does nothing.